# PHP Packages and Importing

Tags: php

I want to have a normal type of class structure like

```
com.acme.module.Class.php
```

So how can import packages like this

In other languages I could do something like

```
import "com.acme.module.Class"
```

or

```
import "com.acme.module.*"
```

Is this possible in with PHP

Comment: Yep ... Php has it. The syntax is quite different. [php import](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PHP 5.3 and higher, we have Namespaces.

According to [PSR-0 standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md), package names are in the form of directory names. i.e. if I have a class `Mauris\Acme\Controllers\Home` (package name is `Mauris\Acme\Controllers` and class name is `Home`), my class file would be named `Home.php` and placed in the folder `src/Mauris/Acme/Controllers`.

Then with an autoloader (there's a [simplified PSR-0 compliant autoloader](https://gist.github.com/221634)), you can directly "import" the classes into your script:

```
<?php
namespace Mauris\Acme\Actions;

require('autoloader.php');
$classLoader = new SplClassLoader();
$classLoader->register(); // register the autoloading callback

// the "import"
// the require() or include() statement is in the auto
use Mauris\Acme\Controllers\Home as HomeController;

$controller = new HomeController();
// if you don't use the "use" statement, you can also write:
// $controller = new \Mauris\Acme\Controllers\Home();
```

Read more at http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: Namespace should be the first construction in the file. Swap it with `require`

Comment: If PSR0 standards are not required, I would simply use spl_autoload_register().

Comment: @jack - possibly too. But I think it's still better to go with a coding standard: you have better integration with other libraries (e.g. through Composer and Packagist).